# Angular debounce (ng-model-options) not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{::vm.placeholder}}" ng-model="vm.value" ng-model-options="{debounce: vm.delay}" ng-change="vm.emitChange()">
```

I am using the "as a vm" syntax, currently it not working when I use  `ng-model-options="{ debounce: vm.delay }"` if I hard coding to `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"` it works.

Comment: Works fine http://plnkr.co/edit/OO89sJ0Om6Kcd5LTVGzc?p=preview

Comment: @dfsq I think that my issue is because of the timeout, see this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/kzh7lJHHCZaOrqdbyPE2?p=preview

Comment: Does that mean your code has a timeout before setting the delay? It might help if you included how you're populating `vm` if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngModelOptions` directive evaluates (with `$scope.$eval`) the value of the `ng-model-options` attribute when the directive's controller first runs. After that, the options consumed by `ngModel` do not change.

from the [src (1.3.15)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.15/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L1217)

```
this.$options = $scope.$eval($attrs.ngModelOptions);
```

In other words, whatever the evaluated value is when the directive runs will "lock in" the options for the `ngModel`.